# Auto publish the newly added comments to all logged in users

Tags: javascript, angular, spring-boot

I am designing the web application using Spring Boot and Angular 6, where we are having multiple documents and user can post the comments on any document.

Type of screen:-

Dashboard:- Divided in 3 parts A) List of Folders :- Personalized directories B) List of documents:- Global documents (Accessible to all users) C) Comments section:- Where we will show all the recent comments for all the documents.

So When User "X" makes any comment to any document that comment should be visible to all logged in users in Section "C" . I am clueless how to achieve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where to even start with this? How are you storing the comments? Are you using some kind of database? As for having "live" changes appear for all connected clients, you could use a WebSocket. Here's a tutorial about using node and WebSockets with an angular client (as a simple chat application) , if it's any help: https://medium.com/factory-mind/angular-websocket-node-31f421c753ff

Comment: Yes we are using mongo DB for storing the database.

Comment: Your question is *way* too broad., Server Sent Events https://golb.hplar.ch/2017/03/Server-Sent-Events-with-Spring.html? Use Firebase https://firebase.google.com/?